# Append timestamps to filenames when splitting audio at silence

Tags: sox

When splitting an audio file at silence e.g.

```
sox input.wav output.wav silence 1 0.5 1% 1 3.0 1% : newfile : restart
```

the multiple output files have filenames like output001.wav, output002.wav, …

Is it possible to instead append the start time of segment within input file?  I.e. if a file has periods of non-silence starting at 1200ms and another at 5000ms, output file names could be something like output1200.wav, output5000.wav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible without modifying SoX. The silence effect does not report in any way at which points it switches from trimming to copying or the other way round.